# Passing data between Ionic 2 pages, data passed is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am using navParams in order to pass data from one page to another. The data is coming back from my server and is valid. But, when I try to pass it to the next page, it's undefined when I console.log the data in the new page.

```
getDataFromServer(accId) {
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/data', {headers:headers})
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.arr = data.accounts.filter((data) => {
          if(data.account_id === accId)
            return {
              amount: data.amount,
              name: data.name
            }
        })
        this.navCtrl.push(NewPage, {
          amount: this.arr.name,
          name: this.arr.name
        })
    });

}

export class NewPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log(this.navParams.get('amount'));
  }

}
```

the amount gets logged as undefined. If i pass in a string for as the 2nd param, then I can successfully console log that string in the new page. Is my array being passed not being evaluated properly? and/or is there an updated way to pass data from one page to the next in Ionic2?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is `async` operation you need to do it as shown below.

**Note:** Concept is there.Hope it as syntax errors.

```
getDataFromServer(accId) {
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/data', {headers:headers})
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.arr = data.accounts.filter((data) => {
          if(data.account_id === accId){
               this.navCtrl.push(NewPage, {
                   amount: data.amount,//you need to get the value here
                   name: data.name
               })
            return {
              amount: data.amount,
              name: data.name
            }
       }
        })

    });

}
```

**Update**

You can try as shown below. i.e. Use `first()` operator.It's like a `promise`.

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';

this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/data', {headers:headers})
        .map(res => res.json())
        .first()
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.arr = data.accounts.filter((data) => {
              if(data.account_id === accId){
                   this.navCtrl.push(NewPage, {
                       amount: data.amount,//you need to get the value here
                       name: data.name
                   })
                return {
                  amount: data.amount,
                  name: data.name
                }
           }
            })

        });
```

Comment: this worked, but it's reloading the newpage everytime a new amount from the or name is passed. If i have 5 names, and I console.log('names') the page reloads every time data is passed.. any thoughts on how to get around this?

Comment: What kind of behavior do you need?

Comment: I think i need the behavior of essentailly a promise. Have the server send back the object with all the data points (from different dates usually over the last few weeks) and pass that object to the NewPage so I can render the data. 

rn, each data point is being passed one at a time.

Comment: Please see the **Update**

Answer (score 0):

What about returning a promise after `filter` is done and `if` condition is fulfilled.

```
getDataFromServer(accId) {
  var self = this;
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/data', {headers:headers})
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.arrPromise = data.accounts.filter((data) => {
            return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject){
              if(data.account_id === accId){
                fulfill([data.amount, data.name]);
              }
              else{
                reject("error");
              }
            }
          });
        });
        this.arrPromise.then(function(result){
          console.log(result) //[data.amount, data.name]
          self.navCtrl.push(NewPage, {
            amount: result[0],
            name: result[1]
          })
        }).catch(function(reject){
          console.log(reject);
        });
    });
}
```